# Extjs Ext.data.Connection in "requestcomplete" stop proceeding further process

Tags: extjs

In my application we are using many grids and many ajax request, my requirement is, If session is timed out say alert msg to user and redirect to login page.

For that i have used the Ext.data.Connection ("requestcomplete" event) like below..

```
Ext.util.Observable.observeClass(Ext.data.Connection);

Ext.data.Connection.on('requestcomplete', function (dataconn, response, option) {
    if (IsSessionTimedOut) // its sets true when Session TimedOut
    {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Responce Status', 'Your session has expired.', function () {
        RedirectToLogin() //});
        //  i neeed to break here (i.e it should not proceed further from where the request is made(store or ajax))
    }
});
```

For example if ajax call is made after "requestcomplete" it comes to success event of ajax. i need to break in requestcomplete event itself, it should not go to success event when the session is timed out.

i tried by "return false" its not worked out

how it can be done ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Ext.Ajax.suspendEvents()

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Observable.html#method-Ext.util.Observable-suspendEvents